# I have more than 50,000 documents in my firestore and it is taking more than 30secs to sort and find in limits of 50. how to speedup?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my snipping code of React Native which I am using for my mobile application. I can't wait 30sec for just 50k data. Imagine the time it will take to load in 500k of data or more

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      setLoading(true);
        firestore().collection('FData')
            .orderBy('counter', 'desc') //order using firestore counter
            .limit(50) //limiting value
            .onSnapshot(snapshot => { 
                var items = [];
                snapshot.forEach((doc)=> {
                    items.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
                });
                setLoading(false);
                setList(items);
            })
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

[image: i have tried shifting the position of counter to the top but its also not working]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to sort them in the app.
But I think your main problem - you trying to get 50k items by ONE request. It's to much. 10 item it's ok. More than 100 - it's not ok.

Comment: no, i have set limit to 50 items per page. but its taking time to find counter 1-50.

Comment: @Owais22 its takes time to sort your docs at firestore.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't wait 30sec for just 50k data.

Reading 50k documents, it's way too much data to read in a single go. Bear in mind that, that the query performance in Firestore depends on the number of documents you request and not on the number of documents you search.

So it doesn't really matter if you search for 10 documents in a collection of 100 documents or in a collection that contains 100 MIL documents, the response time will always be the same. So to be able to read data fast, I recommend you load it in smaller chunks. This practice is called pagination and it can be really simple implemented using query cursors if take a look at the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).

Besides that, since everything in Firestore it's about the number of reads you perform, reading 50k documents at once, can be a bit expensive.

Comment: i have already implemented pagination. but i don't want random documents to load. i have made a counter for indexing. so that it can sort and show documents accordingly.

Comment: If you don't want a random order, then call orderBy and indicate a specific field. Have you tried that?

Comment: yes i have specific field as "counter" and ordered it in descending order. but all it takes it is time to find and arrange in descending order. i wanted to find better solution that will take less time

Comment: How many documents are you reading at once?

Comment: just 50 in table format

Comment: i have shifted to mongodb. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can I help you with other information?